# Hidden characters in text column preventing UNLOAD & COPY in redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Importing data with UNLOAD into a redshift instance I exported via COPY fails with:

```
Delimiter not found
```

Looking at the data it's clear why:

```
"full_url"|"http://www.blahblah.com/about.html?....%2F%2Fetc%2Fpasswd\\|"w4NrxtSqsSJ7B6U3Nv2I8SP9300="|"2016-08-17 16:03:08"
```

Notice that there is no double quote after the "passwd\"

When I query out these particular rows from the db

```
> SELECT value, len(value) FROM property WHERE id=1232323

                       value                              | len
----------------------------------------------------------+-------
http://www.blahblah.com/about.html?....%2F%2Fetc%2Fpasswd | 58
```

It says the len is 58, but if you count the length of that string it is actually 57 characters. I believe there are un-displayable characters at the end of this string that are preventing redshift from escaping the string properly on UNLOAD.

I've also tried to manually put quote chars around as part of the query and it did not work, it just literally drops the quote char.

**Does anyone know how I can get this data to load? I'm fine with losing the rows, or changing the data.**

For reference, here are the commands I use to UNLOAD and COPY:

UNLOAD:

```
UNLOAD ('
SELECT
     p.name as name,
     p.value as value,
     p.event_id as event_id,
     e.created_server_ts
FROM
     property p
     JOIN event e ON p.event_id=e.id
')
TO 's3://bucket/data'
WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<KEY>;aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET>'
ESCAPE ADDQUOTES GZIP MANIFEST;
```

COPY:

```
copy property
from 's3://bucket/data' credentials
'aws_access_key_id=<KEY>;aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET>'
escape removequotes gzip manifest ACCEPTINVCHARS as '^';
```

It always fails because of certain rows:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK discarding the offending rows you can add the [MAXERROR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror) operator to your statement. The load will succeed as long as the number of bad records does not exceed the value you assign [MAXERROR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror).

Here is an example:

```
COPY property
FROM 's3://bucket/data' credentials
'aws_access_key_id=<KEY>;aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET>'
ESCAPE REMOVEQUOTES GZIP MANIFEST ACCEPTINVCHARS as '^' MAXERROR 500000;
```

But before discarding the rows, it would be interesting to find out what is the offending character causing the problem. Maybe running a command such as:

```
SELECT p.value, CHAR(RIGHT(p.value,1)) ad ASCII_CODE
FROM property p
WHERE p.id=1232323
```

Then once you know the offending character you can create a case statement in your UNLOAD the statement that addresses the problem.

Comment: This totally worked, I lost 118 rows out of 1 billion and honestly I don't care :) I'm just happy to have the bulk of the data. Thanks so much!